# Command Prompt - Getting "File not found" error while uploading a file using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-upload, ftp

I am learning batch script and trying to upload a file on specific location using batch file but it is not uploading the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
SET HOST=xx.xx.x.x
SET USER=xxxxx
SET PASSWD=xxxxx
SET FILE='C:\Batch\post.txt'
SET PATH='/home/Test1/'

ftp -n %HOST% 
quote %USER%
quote %$PASSWD%
binary
put %FILE%
quit
exit 0
```

When I executes put command manually, it is throwing "file not found" error.

Please help me to find missing parameter.

many thanks in advance

### EDIT

After changing scripts as below , I m getting login error

```
#!/bin/bash
SET HOST=xx.xx.x.x
SET USER=xxxxx
SET PASSWD=xxxxx
SET "FILE=C:\Batch\post.txt"

(
echo quote %USER%
echo quote %$PASSWD%
echo binary
echo put %FILE%
echo quit
) | ftp -n %HOST%
```

> Please login with USER and PASS.  Command line to send Please login
>   with USER and PASS.  Please login with USER and PASS.  Please login
>   with USER and PASS.

Comment: I do not understand your edit. I've already explained what's wrong in my comment. And you didn't fix any of it.

Comment: Sorry , I missed that one

Comment: Are you using cmd in Windows, or bash in Linux? If the former, remove `#!/bin/bash`, if the latter, remove the [[tag:batch-file]] tag and replace it with the [[tag:bash]] and/or [[tag:shell]] tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute `ftp` commands in a batch file by putting them after the `ftp` call. That cannot work.

The `ftp` will be executed and will wait for the commands, not getting any (it's not aware of the batch file). After you manually close `ftp`, the batch file will continue, trying to execute the other commands, not understanding them.

---

You have to put your `ftp` commands into a separate script file (e.g. `ftp.txt`) and then refer to it using:

```
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

Alternative way that avoids using a separate file is using an input redirection:

```
(
echo quote %USER%
echo quote %$PASSWD%
echo binary
echo put %FILE%
echo quit
) | ftp -n %HOST%
```

Comment: Thanks @martin. I tried this but is still throwing same error and with login error
"Please login with USER and PASS.
Command line to send Please login with USER and PASS.
'C:\Batch\post.txtt': File not found"

Comment: @kreya I assume the double-t in `post.txtt` above is a typo... because of this, and as comments are not a good place to include such output, please [edit] the question to show the _exact_ batch-file you're using and the _exact_ output you're getting (copy-paste both as text). If you get that far, the single-quotes (`'`) around your filenames are probably going to cause a problem: `SET "FILE=C:\Batch\post.txt"` would probably be safer.

Comment: The user/pass error is due to your wrong script, it should have been `quote USER %USER%` and `quote PASS %PASSWD%`. -- And the "file not found" is probably due to the quotes around the path, as already commented above by @TripeHound.